# Django nested url different views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two views `CollectionView` and `CatalogView` which are both *APIView*. In my urls I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'diwata-2-smi', CatalogView.as_view()),
    path('diwata-2-smi/collection/', StacCollectionView.as_view()),
]
```

However I cannot access `diwata-2-smi/collection/`, it is pointing me to `CatalogView`. How can I achieve so that I have the endpoint for `CollectionView`?

Comment: why are you using both `url` and `path`?

Comment: I think the url with regex and order of patterns is culprit here..in first pattern using url which is regex supported for more complex look ups and in second its path which is used for simpler routes.. try reversing the order of patterns and if possible use path for both patterns.

Comment: @VishalSingh what should I use only?

Comment: @AshishNautiyal, even if I remove the regex, the catalog is still the endpoint for collection.

Comment: Problem is that `url` function process regex string as input. The most basic example is something like `url(r'^/diwata-2-smi$', CatalogView.as_view())` which contains ^ - start of string and $ - end of string. Without that $ first url just consume everything after `diwata-2-smi` because it does not have end $ tag.